# filtering objects from List with foreach

Tags: c#, linq, list, delegates

Hi Ive got a list of objects but how do I filter it out to another list?

Ex:

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName;
    public string Language;

    public Person (string FirstName, string Language)
    {
        this.FirstName = FirstName;
        this.LastName = Language;            
    }
 }
```

Creates a list:

```
public List<Person> createDummyList()
{
  List<Person> dummyList = new List<Person>();
  dummyList.Add(new Person("Per", "English"));
  dummyList.Add(new Person("Linda", "Spanish"));
}
```

How can I get a List with just the language and then bind it to say a dropdown.? Ive tryed something like this but got a null reference...

```
public void filterList(List<Person> ListToBeFiltered)
{
    List<string> LanguageList = new List<string>();
    ListToBeFiltered.ForEach(delegate(Person P) 
    {
       LanguageList.Add(P.Language);
    });
    DropDown.datasource = LanguageList;
    DropDown.databind();
 }
```

Anyone can point me in the right direction?

Comment: The linq solution has my preference but here you could have just done a simple foreach on your ListToBeFiltered and add its language to your languageList.

Answer (score 4):

```
IEnumerable<string> languageList = listToBeFiltered.Select(p=>p.Language)
                                                   .Distinct()
                                                   .ToList();
```

Comment: You probably just blew his mind. It seems Mr T has some basic concepts to learn. Like returning stuff from methods.

Comment: Heh, that compiler will tell him as soon as he tries to compile without returning.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void filterList(List<Person> ListToBeFiltered)
{
        DropDown.datasource = ListToBeFiltered.Select(p=>p.Language).Distinct();
        DropDown.databind();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your swift replies... But I still got a "null reference" when I tries to databind it to a dropdown..